# How can I automatically add cell values in R based on values in two separate dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am working on a data cleansing project and I want to know how can I adjust values from a cell based on values from another dataframe. For example I have this dataframe that I made for reference to be used when I want to fill cells with another value. I have two dataframes currently. I have this one that I am currently working on.

```
Name

Apple
Carrot
Cheese
```

And this one that I created as a reference legend.

```
Name     Type

Apple    Fruit
Carrot   Vegetable
Cheese   Dairy Product
```

As you can see, I have assigned specific types to each name as a reference so that when I add the column, I know what type corresponds to each name.

I want to add the types. What I am currently doing is this.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Type = ifelse(grepl('Apple', df$name), 'Fruit', Type))
df <- df %>% mutate(Type = ifelse(grepl('Carrot', df$name), 'Vegetable', Type))
df <- df %>% mutate(Type = ifelse(grepl('Cheese', df$name), 'Dairy Product', Type))
```

The code works fine, but I am manually writing the lines for the adjustment. It gets tiring with more and more different values. Is it possible that I can automatically fill the data using data from the other dataframe? for example, instead of manually entering, the code would automatically detect the data from the reference legend and plug it in the the file I am currently working on based on the corresponding values? I want the code to automatically detect if it detects the value has apple, it would reference the reference legend, find that the type is "Fruit" and automatically fill in "Fruit". sorry if my question is not clear, I can clarify further if needed. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe `merge` or `dplyr::*_join`.

Comment: Is this just `df %>% left_join(df2)`? In base R, `merge(df, df2)`.

Comment: No it is not. I have added a column for type in the first dataframe but all the values are blank (NA). Now, I am trying to write a code that will replace the nulls with the value from the second dataframe. For example, now in the first dataframe, the value for type for apple is null, I want to write a code that will detect from the second dataframe that the corresponding value should be "Fruit" and replace the null value with "fruit" in the first dataframe.

Comment: Actually, I got to do it. I used left_join. Thanks!